# Swift time zones converting issue

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdate

In my playground i create a simple code example to convert time from my local zone to `"America/Sao_Paulo"`.

```
let gmtDf: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
gmtDf.timeZone = NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone();
gmtDf.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let gmtDate: NSDate = NSDate.new()

print(gmtDate)

let estDf: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
estDf.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "America/Sao_Paulo")
estDf.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
let estDate: NSDate = estDf.dateFromString(gmtDf.stringFromDate(gmtDate))!

print(estDate)
```

All code is working fine, but i have a question that is connected with code output.Why printed output show time 2 hours before my local time. And converted time is in 2000 year.

[image]

Comment: Same is here!!! while taking cursor on date it shows UTC and while printing it shows different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `NSTimeZone.systemTimeZone` will return GMT time if it cannot determine the system time zone, I'm guessing that's what's happening here since you're using a Playground.
2. You're only using the hour, minutes and seconds to convert from date to string `dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"` so that String doesn't have any information about the year, that's why when you're using that to convert back to a NSDate it's showing 2000, since it doesn't have the proper info to know what year it is.